# Hausdorff metric and $\varepsilon$-thickenings

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fractals

Let $h(A,B)$ be the Hausdorff metric defined by:
$$
h(A,B)=\inf\{\varepsilon >0 \; | \; A \subseteq B_\varepsilon, B \subseteq A_\varepsilon \},
$$

where $A_\varepsilon$ is the $\varepsilon$-thickening of $A$ defined by $ A_\varepsilon = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \;|\; \exists a \in A,\; d(a,x)\le  \varepsilon\}$ (and $d$ is the Euclidian metric).

I am wondering whether $(A_{\varepsilon})_\delta=A_{\varepsilon+\delta}$.

It is fairly easy to show that:$(A_{\varepsilon})_\delta \subseteq A_{\varepsilon+\delta}$: Let $x \in (A_\varepsilon)_\delta$. Then there is a $y\in A_{\varepsilon}$ such that $d(x,y)\le \delta$. And since $y\in A_{\varepsilon}$, there is a $z \in A$ such that $d(y,z)\le \varepsilon$. By summing the two inequalities, and by the triangular inequality: $d(x,z)\in A_{\varepsilon+\delta}$.

But the other inclusion is trickier and I cannot manage to find a counter example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't work if the metric has more than one point and is such that each pair of distinct points is a distance $1$ apart (use $\epsilon=\delta=\frac{2}{3}$), but I believe it's true for any normed space, and probably for any convex metric space. For the edit you just made, restricting things to ${\mathbb R}^{n},$ it seems fairly straightforward to me to prove true---is every point that is a distance of $\epsilon + \delta$ from $x$ (i.e. within the $\epsilon+\delta$ sphere about $x$) also a distance $<\delta$ from some $y$ that itself is $<\epsilon$ from $x$--but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: How can we be sure there is such a $y$ ? Is it enough to say one can take the $y$ in $A_\varepsilon$ at the intersection between the segment $[x,z]$ and the boundary of $A_\varepsilon$?

Comment: My thinking was that if $z$ is a distance of $\epsilon + \delta - \eta $ from $x$ for some possibly very small $\eta > 0,$ then an appropriate $y$ can be found on the segment joining $x$ and $z$ by choosing $y$ to be on the segment and at a distance of $\epsilon - \frac{1}{2}\eta$ (which is less than $\epsilon$) from $x$ and noticing that $y$ is a distance of $\delta - \frac{1}{2}\eta$ (less than $\delta$) from $z.$ For why I think it might be true for convex metric spaces in general, see the Wikipedia entry [Convex metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_metric_space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave L. Renfro said in a comment, in general  the inclusion $(A_{\varepsilon})_\delta\subseteq A_{\varepsilon+\delta}$ may be strict. For example, consider $A=\{0\}$ in the metric space $\mathbb{Z}$ with the natural metric. Here $(A_{1/2})_{1/2}=\{0\}$ but $A_1 = \{-1,0,1\}$.

Equality $(A_{\varepsilon})_\delta = A_{\varepsilon+\delta}$ holds in all *geodesic* metric spaces [Definition: a space is geodesic if for any two points, there is a path between them whose length equals the distance between the points.] More generally, it holds in spaces $X$ with the following property: for every $x,y\in X$ and every $t\in [0,1]$ there is $z\in X$ such that 
$$d(z,x)=td(x,y)\quad\text{ and }\quad d(z,y)=(1-t)d(x,y)$$

Proof: let $p\in  A_{\varepsilon+\delta}$ and choose $r>{\varepsilon+\delta}$. There is $a\in A$ such that $d(p,a)<r$. By the assumption, there is $z\in X$ such that $d(z,a)=\varepsilon$ and $d(z,p)=r-\varepsilon$. Hence $d(p,A_\varepsilon)\le r-\varepsilon$. Since this holds for every $r>{\varepsilon+\delta}$, we have $d(p,A_\varepsilon)\le \delta$.

Comment: Nice! I suppose you mean $d(z,p)<r-\varepsilon$ ?